# Formulários no Joomla com limite de submissão

Tags: formulário, joomla

Bom dia, gostaria de cria um formulário no Joomla e queria saber se existe algum módulo de formulário (chronoforms, form maker, etc...) que me permitisse limitar o número de inscrições?

Pois o local onde o evento irá ocorrer tem número limitado de lugares.

---

Hello, I would like to create a form in Joomla and would like to know if there is any form module (chronoforms, form maker, etc ...) that would allow me to limit the number of registrations?

Because the place where the event will occur has a limited number of places.